# Apache NiFi & Kafka Integration

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I am not sure this questions is already addressed somewhere, but I couldn't find a helpful answer anywhere on internet.

I am trying to integrate Apache NiFi with Kafka - consuming data from Kafka using Apache NiFi. Below are few questions that comes to my mind before proceeding with this.

Q-1) The use case that we have is - read data from Kafka real time, parse the data, do some basic validations on the data and later push the data to HBase. I know
 Apache NiFi is the right candidate for doing this kind of processing, but how easy it is to build the workflow if the JSON that we are processing is a complex one ? We were 
 initially thinking of doing the same using Java Code, but later realised this can be done with minimum effort in NiFi. Please note, 80% of data that we are processing from 
 Kafka would be simple JSONs, but 20% would be complex ones(invovles arrays)

Q-2) The trickiest part while writing Kafka consumer is handling the offset properly. How Apache NiFi will handle offsets while consuming from Kafka topics ? How offsets
 would be properly committed in case rebalancing is triggered while processing ? The frameworks like Spring-Kafka provide options to commit the offsets (to some extent) in case 
 rebalance is triggered in the middle of processing. How NiFi handles this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have deployed a number of pipeline in 3 node NiFi cluster in production, out of which one is similar to your use case.

Q-1) It's very simple and easy to build a pipeline for your use-case. Since you didn't mention the types of tasks involved in `processing` a json, I'm assuming generic tasks. Generic task involving JSONs can be schema validation which can be achieved using `ValidateRecord` Processor, transformation using `JoltTransformRecord` Processor, extraction of attribute values using `EvaluateJsonPath`, conversion of json to some other format say avro using `ConvertJSONToAvro` processors etc.
Nifi gives you flexibility to scale each stage/processor in the pipelines independently. For example, if transformation using JoltTransformRecord is time consuming, you can scale it to run `N` concurrent tasks in each node by configuring `Concurrent Tasks` under `Scheduling` tab.

Q-2) As far as `ConsumeKafka_2_0` processor is concerned, the offset management is handled by committing the NiFi processor session first and then the Kafka offsets which means we have an at-least once guarantee by default. 
When Kafka trigger rebalancing of consumers for a given partition, processor quickly commits(processor session and Kafka offset) whatever it has got and will return the consumer to the pool for reuse.

ConsumeKafka_2_0 handles committing offset when members of the consumer group change or the subscription of the members changes. This can occur when processes die, new process instances are added or old instances come back to life after failure.  Also taken care for cases where the number of partitions of subscribed topic is administratively adjusted.

Comment: Pushpavanthar, regarding Q-1, Do you have experience working with complex JSONs (which involves multiple arrays). Do we need to write customer processors for handling complex ones ? Regarding q-2, does NiFi will handle committing offsets irrespective of reason for rebalance ?

Comment: Q-1) I'm sure Jolt Transformer can handle any kind of nester JSON. You'll have to invest little time in understanding jolt spec and derive one for your use case. I can help you if you can give a concrete example of json payload and kind of processing you are looking for. Q-2) I've updated above answer with more details.